# Test a branch with Jasmine Karma

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I was wondering how I can test a branch with Jasmin/Karma within Angular.
For example I have this simple function:

```
  loadData(){
    if(this.faktor){ // here it should be true or false
      this.callMethod1();
    }else{
      this.callMethod2();
    }
  }
```

I will need to increase the test coverage and it is needed to test the branches. I tried with the example below but it is not working. I need to set the this.factor.isExist() to true. How can I do it?

**Here is my test component:**

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { ChartComponent } from './chart.component';

describe('ChartComponent', () => {
  let component: ChartComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ChartComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ ChartComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ChartComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should call method1  if factor exist', () => {
    const spy =  spyOn(component, 'callMethod1');
    component.factor.isExist() as true;
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  })

  it('should call method2 if factor not exist', () =>{
    const spy =  spyOn(component, 'callMethod2');
    component.factor.isExist() as false;
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  })
});
```

Comment: What is your problem here? And where are you calling `loadData()` method?

Comment: It is just an example. I can call is from Html file or from other function. You can choose it. I need to test the branches and the if statement should be test if is true and false. How can I set the this.riskfaktor to true and false? Is this the best way to test branches?

Comment: Well  you can simply set `component.factor = null` for negative condition and `component.factor = some data` for positive test.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is always not possible to make code coverage 100%, but yours is a very simple case, where you can cover all the code that you are showing here.

```
it('should call method1  if factor exist', () => {
    const spy =  spyOn(component, 'callMethod1');
    component.factor = 'Your mock data goes here'
    component.loadData();       // should execute if part
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  })

  it('should call method2 if factor not exist', () =>{
    const spy =  spyOn(component, 'callMethod2');
    component.factor = null;    
    component.loadData();     // should execute else part
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  })
```

Comment: Would it also work if factor will be const factor within a function?

Comment: You can set one time value to the constant variable of a component. It could be from test spec as well.

Comment: Do you have an example of it?

Comment: You can probably create another question with your requirement. So that it's more clear what you are asking